# How to hide keyboard in swift on pressing return key on entire app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

We can change the **tintColor** of the entire app in the ***appDelegate***, so...

> is it possible to hide the keyboard pressing **return key** to all
>   textFields in a viewController or in the entire app

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `self.view.endEditing(true)` this method helps you to resign first responder all textField in your view controller.

Comment: But where do I call it ? I don't want to assign delegate to all my textFields in the ViewController.

Comment: If you want to hide after pressing return key then you have to set the delegate to the viewcontroller then call this method in the textFieldShouldReturn delegate method. Other wise when you need to hide keyborad then call this method from anywhere in your view controller.